# why Does fs throw error on routing to new page, but refreshing page works?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Issue:

I am building an NextJs app that has 4 input fields. All of these fields have a set options list. for now I am reading those options in as a json included in the project. The user can select those 2 fields then click a button to go to a search page. The user can then select a button on the search page to navigate back to home. The project seems to load fine when run, but if I navigate to the search results page and back to home (both navigations are done using Link from next/link) I get `TypeError: fs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_17___default.a.readFileSync is not a function` as show by the following

[image]

As you can see this is happening on the home page's `getInitialProps()` call. This call seems to work as expected when the site starts, and only has an issue when navigating to the page from another page, but this error goes away and all functionality is restored when the page is refreshed. for some reason it doesn't seem to recognize the `fs` import on rerouting, but does fine when refreshed. Does anyone know how to resolve this error apart from reloading the window

pages/index.js:

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';
import FilterBox from '../components/filter-box';
import GreetingBlock from '../components/greeting-block';
import Layout, { siteTitle } from '../components/layout';
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css';
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import blue from '@material-ui/core/colors/blue';
import orange from '@material-ui/core/colors/orange';
import fs from 'fs';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: blue[500],
    },
    secondary: {
      main: orange[500],
    },
  },
});
class Home extends Component {
  static async getInitialProps() {
    const inputsraw = await fs.readFileSync('./data/inputs.json');
    const inputs = await JSON.parse(inputsraw);
    // console.log('====================')
    return inputs
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      area: '',
      day: '',
      startTime: '',
      endTime: '',
      features: '',
    }
  }
  render() {
    // console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Layout home>
          <Head>
            <title>{siteTitle}</title>
          </Head>
          <GreetingBlock></GreetingBlock>
          <FilterBox inputs={this.props}></FilterBox>
        </Layout>
      </ThemeProvider>
    )
  }
}

export default Home;
```

pages/search.js:

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import { Component } from 'react';
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { getSearchData } from '../lib/search';
import blue from '@material-ui/core/colors/blue';
import orange from '@material-ui/core/colors/orange';
import Layout, { siteTitle } from '../components/layout';
import fs from 'fs'

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: blue[500],
    },
    secondary: {
      main: orange[500],
    },
  },
});

export default class Search extends Component {
  static async getInitialProps() {
    try {
      const inputsraw = await fs.readFileSync('./data/inputs.json');
      const inputs = await JSON.parse(inputsraw);
      console.log('====================');
      return inputs
    }
    catch {
      return {}
    }
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props);
  }
  
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.areas);
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Layout>
                <Head>
                    <title>{siteTitle}</title>
                </Head>
                <h1>HIII</h1>
                <div>{JSON.stringify(this.props.areas)}</div>
            </Layout>
        </ThemeProvider>
      )
    }
}
```

versions:

next: 10.1.3

react: 17.0.2

I am running on WSL2 if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refreshing the page causes it to be generated using server-side rendering.

Normal navigation triggers client-side rendering.

The `fs` module depends on APIs provided by Node.js and not by web browsers (i.e. the ability to access the server's hard disk).

---

Provide the JSON through an API page and access it using `fetch` as per the [React AJAX and APIs FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html).